# Using the same jade view for edit and create

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Hopefully this isn't too stupid question as I attempt to get my head around node.

I've been looking at the express framework and am trying to get my head around the simple problem of a create/edit view.

If I have a jade view as below:

```
input(name='bar', id='bar', value=#{foo.bar})
```

The view expects the property foo.bar on the model I pass back, fine for an edit screen. However if this is a create screen I don't really want to have to pass back an empty model. How should this be dealt with? Is it just a case that I have to pass back an empty model? If so any pointers to a pattern for this would be great.

Thanks.

(I know I'm missing something fundamental)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this myself by simply always making sure that there's a foo-object, and then referencing foo.bar anyway. This can be done in a lot of ways. You could hijack res.render or use your own custom render method, like so (somwhere when initalizing):

```
express.response.renderFooAdmin = function (view, data, callback) {
    data.foo = data.foo || {};
    this.render(view, data, callback);
};
```

And in your route:

```
res.renderFooAdmin('view', data);
```

And reference the object directly instead of via a #{} block to not print "undefined":

```
input(name='bar', id='bar', value=foo.bar)
```

Comment: Ahh, I haven't got node to hand, but as long as the parent property is there you can try and reference a child. If it doesn't exist then it will print nothing? So if bar isn't there?

Comment: Yes indeed. `undefined.bar` is not valid while `({}).bar` is undefined but valid. When Jade encounters an undefined property printed with `attr=obj.prop`, it's not printed. If you use `attr="#{obj.prop}"`it will be interpreted as a string 'undefined', which usually is not what you want. (Not sure what happens with `attr=#{obj.prop}`, have never tried that)

Comment: Interesting. I will try later. However for now, consider your answer correct :D